# Best way to store serverside data?

Tags: php, mysql, server-side, writetofile

What is the best way to store data on the server, that can be updated using PHP?

In my case I am storing a number.
Should I use:

- MySQL table
- .TXT document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to search, update and order data, you can use a .txt file.... but if you need to query data, i highly recommend a database (MySQL for example).

If you store just one number, you can do it using a .txt file.

Comment: What do you mean by "search data"? I just want to store a number on the server, that I can retrieve when needed using PHP.

Comment: If its just a number, use a .txt file.

Comment: By search i mean "select records" (if you had multiple records, of course)