# Best way to store 1 variable server-side

Tags: php, variables

I want to store just 1 PHP variable, with only 2 options, Yes or No. 
But im was thinking, whats the best way to do this?
Is the best way to use a MySQL Database? A file? What?

A TXT file was recommanded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628583/best-way-to-store-serverside-data), but how can i use that properly? What CHMod? Is it safe?

Comment: @Chris Burt-Brown I said it in the post, a "yes" or a "no"

Comment: Store permanently or store for the user's session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "Yes or No" can be converted to "1 or 0" or "has or not has", you could simply add a file. If it exists, it means "YES". If not, it means "NO".

Random link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#Lock_files

Comment: Give an example please, because i don't understand how you can write in a file without fread or fwrite.

Comment: chmod depends on your configuration. create the file using `fopen` or `touch`: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10100159.html Remove the file using `unlink`.

Comment: You don't need to write **IN** the file. Only its existance tells you `YES`.

Comment: But how do i CHMod the file to delete it?

Comment: You do not need to chmod it. Usually, if you can add a file you can remove this file.

Comment: don't worry about chmod, the user who creates the file is also the one deleting it.

Answer (score -1):

Since it is server side better to use Sessions

```
<?php
session_start();
//for yes
if(yes){
$_SESSION['flag']=1;
}
.
.
.
.
//While using that sessions
if(isset($_SESSIONS,'flag')){
  //t
}
else{
}
```

Comment: It needs to be stored permanently. Server-side. If it changes that needs to be visible for everyone. Not just you.

Comment: Session values depend on the user and are not persistant beyond the time the session expires.